# All my pages have canonical except home page. I still get Duplicate, submitted URL not selected as canonical

Tags: google-search-console, google-search

In my website, All other pages have canonical urls in the head section like so:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/" />
```

The only page without canonical is the home page `'/'`

When I go to google search console, I keep getting this error:

**URL is not on Google**

Duplicate, submitted URL not selected as canonical

```
Discovery
Sitemaps
https://example.com/sitemap.xml
Referring page
None detected
```

Every time I fetch, I hope it will get fix but not happening. Should I add canonical on the home page too pointing itself?

Comment: Do all the canonical URLs on all the sub-pages point to the home page?   If so, that could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I see the message: URL is on Google

[image]

My site is a local business site with static pages for products, services, about etc. They have somehow similar content but not exactly. Here is what I did to fix:

- Added canonical link on all pages including home page
- All those canonical links are pointing to home page 'domain.com/'
- Resubmitted the sitemap
- After about 2 hours, when I ran the URL Inspection test, It was showing its is in google index.

Canonical link in the head section of all pages:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/" />
```

UPDATE: I have added canonical url on each pages including home page. All of them point to itself. I am doing this because I don't have duplicate content. Few pages are already showing up in google search on page 1/2

Comment: As Stephen mentioned, if all your pages are canonicalising to the home page you will have a problem. Each page needs to canonicalise to itself.

Comment: @TonyMcCreath I have added canonical on each page pointing to themself instead of home page because I don’t really have any duplication. Let’s see what happens.